# Can I create a Form using the new Office Add-ins?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, office-js

In PowerPoint VBA I can create a `UserForm` (`MSForms`) and call:

```vba
Dim frm As New myUserForm 

frm.Show
```

The result is a Window on top of PowerPoint.

Can I do the same thing from `JavaScript API for Office`?

Is the full Microsoft PowerPoint Object Library available from JavaScript API for Office*?

The new add-ins were not designed with the intention to replace the old VBA Add-ins, but porting VBA to JS seems logic and my Add-in could take advantage of some of the new online services of Office 365.

Comment: The PowerPoint JavaScript API for Office is not available jet. Even though already depreciated, VBA and VSTO Add-ins are the only options today.

Comment: PPT has supported this new add-in model for several versions. This video might be of help https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Build/2016/P551  My understanding is that it wants to use panes rather than forms.

Comment: You can lobby for this API here: https://powerpoint.uservoice.com/forums/288949-powerpoint-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/13582668-allow-javascript-code

Answer (score 1):

This isn't support by Office.js.

Office Web Add-ins were designed to be a cross-platform framework and the `frm` object only exists on Windows. It's also a native object which doesn't fit into a web based framework.

Instead of using a native object, consider building your form in HTML/JS. You can still display this as a modal dialog using the [Dialog API](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) if you wish.